# How to detect (from installer) if SQL Reporting is installed in the server?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

I'm working on a Windows Installer project (via InstallShield) that will perform some work with SQL Reporting Services.

Does anybody know what is the safest way to detect if SQL Reporting services are installed in the target machine?

So far I've found that:

1. I could check for the MSSQLSERVER service 
   or
2. Check the registry for the following key:

   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{0C270C59-8706-42B8-A2AD-6E5EE18BC90B}`

I've always preferred to use the registry in order to find something is installed, but I'm not sure this is the correct key in this case. (I'm aware that searching for that particular registry key would only match SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services, which in my case would be fine).

Note: I'm leaning towards using the registry entry search, but an alternative method using C# code would be fine if someone knows how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the best approach is doing it programmatically through a custom action:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630446.aspx

You can find a custom action tutorial here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/msicustomaction.aspx

Please note that only win32 DLL and VBScript custom actions can set installer properties. So a .NET installer class action won't work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Cosmin. I've gone through the technet link and found the ReportingService2006.ServerInfoHeaderValue that reports the "version" programmatically, however it seems like in order to run the function the Reporting services must be already installed. The reason I want to know if the services are installed is in order to stop the installer in cases where the services are not in the machine. The only thing I think of is trying to run the function and if it fails then assume the services are not available and stop the installer, I don't like it that much, but could work.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment above I'm no longer trying to detect if SSRS is installed, instead I'm calling the web service and if it doesn't respond or fails I'm assuming it is not installed, which in my case it's just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SSRS\MSSQLServer\CurrentVersion

Here is described how to check if SQL Server Reporting Services is installed via Actual Installer:
https://www.actualinstaller.com/help/prerequisites.html